# assigning class to second element Java Script

Tags: javascript, widget, twitter

I'm using JS function to pull twitter feeds, I only would like to display two tweets at the time but i would like to assign unique css class to second element (div) I'm not sure how to do that could anyone help with that, here is my code

```
JQTWEET = {

    // Set twitter username, number of tweets & id/class to append tweets
    user: 'username',
    numTweets: 2,
    appendTo: '#jstwitter',

    // core function of jqtweet
    loadTweets: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {
                screen_name: JQTWEET.user,
                include_rts: true,
                count: JQTWEET.numTweets,
                include_entities: true
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

             var html = '<div class="tweet">TWEET_TEXT';

                 // append tweets into page
                 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $(JQTWEET.appendTo).append(
                        html.replace('TWEET_TEXT', JQTWEET.ify.clean(data[i].text))
                            .replace(/USER/g, data[i].user.screen_name)
                            .replace('AGO', JQTWEET.timeAgo(data[i].created_at))
                            .replace(/ID/g, data[i].id_str)
                    );

                 }                  
            }   

        });

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  $(JQTWEET.appendTo)
   .append('<span class="'+((i%2==0)?"even":"odd")+'">')
   .append(
     html.replace('TWEET_TEXT', JQTWEET.ify
     .clean(data[i].text))
     .replace(/USER/g, data[i].user.screen_name)
     .replace('AGO', JQTWEET.timeAgo(data[i].created_at))
     .replace(/ID/g, data[i].id_str)
    .append('</span>');
}
```

Comment: thank you for help for some reason code breaks and not displaying tweets at all here is my code
` // append tweets into page
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     $(JQTWEET.appendTo).append('<span class="'+((i%2==0)?"even":"odd")+'">')
        .append(
        html.replace('TWEET_TEXT', JQTWEET.ify.clean(data[i].text))
       .replace(/USER/g, data[i].user.screen_name)
       .replace('AGO', JQTWEET.timeAgo(data[i].created_at))
       .replace(/ID/g, data[i].id_str)
       .append('</span>');

     );

     } `

Comment: Look in the console. I am sure I missed a quote or something. the important stuff is `.append('<span class="'+((i%2==0)?"even":"odd")+'">')` and the last `.append('</span>');`